# ASP.NET Core 6 randomly returning 200 with empty response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a web app deployed on Azure. During testing, I found one of my endpoints is not working... sometimes. More specifically, this `POST` endpoint always works in my dev environment, and it randomly works in Prod.

When it fails, my controller endpoint is not hit (discovered by adding logs), and a "successful" 200 is returned but no response content is sent down. My `POST` body is tiny, only 50 or so bytes.

I'm not sure if its a clue or not, but it does seem to work immediately after a browser refresh, then when my auth token is refreshed it fails much more. This is fairly anecdotal though.

From googling, I found this helps some people:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
    options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
});
```

No such luck here though. Any ideas what else might caused this? OR, any idea how how I can have .NET better tell me what's failing? I have nothing in my logs or anything.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I  have two middlewares:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions jsonPolicy = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = context.Response;

        string msg;
        switch (exception)
        {
            case ApplicationException ex:
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Invalid Token"))
                {
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    msg = ex.Message;
                    break;
                }
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                msg = ex.Message;
                break;
            default:
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                msg = exception.Message;
                break;
        }
        var errorResponse = new
        {
            Failed = true,
            ErrorMessage = msg
        };

        _logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse, jsonPolicy);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class UserStatusMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly DbContextFactory DbContextFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions jsonPolicy = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };

    public UserStatusMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, DbContextFactory dbrderMonkeyContextFactory, ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        DbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        using (DBContext dbContext = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var user = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            AspNetUser dbUser = dbContext.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Value);
            if (dbUser.IsDisabled || !dbUser.IsApproved)
            {
                httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var response = httpContext.Response;

                string msg;
                var errorResponse = new
                {
                    Failed = true,
                    IsDisabled = dbUser.IsDisabled,
                    IsApproved = dbUser.IsApproved,
                    ErrorMessage = "User is either disabled or not approved"
                };
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

                var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse, jsonPolicy);
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
            else
            {
                _next(httpContext);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class UserStatusMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseUserStatusCheck(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<UserStatusMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

EDIT #2: So it looks like if I take out the second middleware, the problem goes away. But why? Is there some time limit for middleware?

Comment: Do you have any custom middleware in your pipeline?

Comment: @ArcherBird see edits

Comment: How are you observing the 200 and failures, you should track the request and response on the client side for this, should reveal if a cached response is the issue. Also reduce your deployment instances to 1 to remove any cross server issues or load balancing issues. Make sure you are testing the right version of your code ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller yeah, client is reporting 200 response code, no body. cacching is disabled, and i'm POSTing different data each time.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller also, only running a single instance on azure.